# Should we merge "database-theory", "databases" and "dbms"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are at least three tags that refer to databases: [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases), [database-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-theory), and [dbms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dbms). The tag [dbms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dbms) is hardly used, but the other two are both reasonably common.

Should we merge all three of them?

Comment: I'd say [tag:databases] and [tag:dbms] are synonyms, but distinct from [tag:database-theory]. I'd tag a question about relational algebra with the latter, but one about writing/improving a certain SQL query the former (if it's ontopic at all).

Comment: Can you think of a question appropriate for [cs.se] which should be tagged [tag:databases] rather than [tag:database-theory]?

Comment: [This one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60525/why-must-uncommitted-transactions-be-undone-in-backwards-order). But then, it all comes down to the semantics of "theory" in this term.

Comment: Fair enough. Though in practice, the tags are probably used interchangeably.

Comment: Yup. I've given up years ago to try and ensure reasonable tagging. #shrug#

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the questions with [dbms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dbms), and all of them were about [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases). Since I saw no one disagreeing with this part of the proposal, I went ahead with merging them and making [dbms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dbms) a synonym of [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases)

As for [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases) vs. [database-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-theory), we *could* merge [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases) into [database-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-theory) without making a synonym. This means that all current questions tagged with [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases) will be retagged into [database-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-theory), but since the tags are not synonyms, it is still possible to tag a question with [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases) without being part of [database-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-theory).

However, it seems to me that as a tag, [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases) and [database-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-theory) provide about the same information about the question, and this is reflected in most of the questions in this tag. So I instead suggest to both merge and synonymize [databases](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases) into [database-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-theory), because this seems to reflects the usage of the tags the best. (maybe the tag description could also be updated...) I can go ahead and perform this merge once I see enough support (i.e. votes or comments) for this decision.